# Convert docx to pdf using PHP

Tags: php

I am currently generating multiple .docx files using PHPWord. I need to find a way to combine these docx files and save them as 1 pdf file. Is there a way that this can be done?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the generated docx with PHPDOCX http://www.phpdocx.com/

```
    require_once 'phpdocx_pro/classes/TransformDoc.inc';
    $docx = new TransformDoc();
    $docx->setStrFile('document.docx');
    $docx->generateXHTML();
    $html = $docx->getStrXHTML();
```

Also, you can export the docx to PDF with

```
    $docx->generatePDF();
```

*Note this is not a free library*

Comment: Yeah if I'm going to do that I might as well purchase PHPDOCX and use it to generate the docx. I was thinking about doing it anyway; just trying to see if there is a free alternative out there. I'm also not a fan of purchasing a new license for each domain/subdomain.

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't work very well...I start from a WORD2007 document, generated with PHPWord (contains tables, photos,...but no graphs) and your PHPDOCX produces a PDF file but with some data are displayed but not all (actually, most of the data are not displayed) and no image at all...You can see here: from [link]https://www.box.com/s/cbf2243c6cb0cf782a08 and the PDF converted using your code is: [link]https://www.box.com/s/600a4f83d4db987baa1e

Comment: Too bad that that doesn't work with the community version of phpdocx. "Class 'DOMPDF' not found"

Comment: DOMPDF can be downloaded from github. Works, but the PDFs are far from the original.

Comment: I tried PhpDocx and I agree with Yoog Kim, it didn't do a great job. Images disappear, my parsed content has a line on top for some reason, text justified, wrong font type and size. The only useful thing is that is a readable PDF, that's it!

Comment: I think you should mention it's not free in your answer

Comment: do you have another free solution on this?

Answer (score -7):

```
  /**
   * return the pdf stream as a string returned from the function
   */
  function  output($debug = false) {
  ...
  }
```

so just write the result of 'generatePDF()' to a file.

for example:

```
$content = $docx->generatePDF();
$myfile = fopen("newfile.pdf", "w");
fwrite($myfile, $content);
fclose($myfile);
```