# Is WebKit's WebView (OS X) able to display docx file?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, webkit, docx

I wanted to use a WebView (notice: it's not UIWebView present in iOS, I'm talking about Mac OS X WebView) to display docx document in my Mac application, but it fails to load it.

Code I'm using:

```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo.docx" ofType:nil];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];   
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [[self.webViewPlaceholder mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

(demo.docx is demo file from Calibre project).

From `WebResourceLoadDelegate` method `webView:resource:didFailLoadingWithError:fromDataSource:` I'm getting:

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo=0x608000075500 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=about:blank, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted, NSErrorFailingURLKey=about:blank}
```

Does this mean that WebView is unable to display this kind of document?

It's a bit surprising, while the same code in a sample iOS project presents the same demo file without any issues.

Dragging demo.docx directly onto the Safari tab do not load a document, so I guess this format is basically not supported by WebKit under Mac OS X?

If my assumptions are correct, what would be the best approach to display docx file content? Conversion to PDF? To HTML?

Comment: You could watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuF2MGX0Os8 (libopc & WebKit)

Answer (score 0):

The only apps that can open Docx on Mac OS X are Word, Pages, or other similar programs. I would really wonder if you could open a docx from a browser.

I suggest you to convert the docx to PDF or HTML, but I'm not aware of any librarys doing that client-side. YOu could use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299030/convert-docx-to-pdf-using-php#9299276 for PHP for example.